# Crash due to getchar

Tags: c, getchar

The main function code is as follows:

```
#define MEM_INCR 20    

int main(void)
{
char *str = NULL, **s_words = NULL, *temp = NULL, *tempbuf = NULL;
int wordcount = 0, i, length = 0, memo = 0;

do
{
    if(length >= memo)
    {
        memo += MEM_INCR;
        if(!(tempbuf = realloc(str, memo)))
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failed.");
            return 1;
        }
        str = tempbuf;;
    }
}
while((str[length++] = getchar()) != '\n');
str[--length] = '\0';

wordcount = word_count(str);

s_words = malloc(wordcount); //Allocate sufficient memory to store words
for(i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) //Now allocate memory to store each word
    s_words[i] = calloc(MAX_LENGTH, sizeof(char)); //Use this function in order not to have unfilled space
segment(str, s_words); //Segment the string into words

printf("Words sorted: \n"); //Output the message
for(i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) //Short the words from the shortest to the longest
{
    if(strcmp(s_words[i], s_words[i + 1]) > 0) //Check if the first word is longer than the second
    {
        temp = s_words[i]; //Store the first address in temp
        s_words[i] = s_words[i + 1]; //Assign the successive address to the previous one
        s_words[i + 1] = temp; //Assign the first to the successive
        temp = NULL; //Ensure NULL in order to avoid leaks
    }
    printf("%s", s_words[i]); //Output the words ordered
}
return 0;
}
```

The program works fine if i have a fixed string supplied to it or if i use the gets() function, but when i am using the above code in order to be able and receive a string of any length i get a crash. The function that are present are working correctly, the only problem is when using getchar. Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Put return value of `getchar` to `int` and check for error/EOF. Try using functions. Avoid "clever"/terse code, for example separate assignment from conditions. Use debugger or debug prints (hint, you are allocating 0 bytes there, if I see correctly).

Comment: 1) `s_words = malloc(wordcount);` --> `s_words = malloc(wordcount*sizeof(char*));`

Comment: 2) `i < wordcount;` --> `i < wordcount-1;` for `s_words[i + 1]`

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, i'm not allocating 0 bytes but the increase as MEM_INCR.

Comment: It is here `s_words = malloc(wordcount)` that you are allocating 0 bytes, since wordcount starts a 0 and never changes (at least in the code you have shown us).

Comment: It was not copied in the initial code and now i have added the `wordcount = word_count(str);`. The wordcount is not 0 assuming a successful string input.

Comment: makes more sense now, thanks'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
do {
    /* ... */
} while((str[length++] = getchar()) != '\n');
```

But the definition of `getchar()` is `int getchar(void)`.  The `getchar()` function is defined to return an `int` for good reason -- it needs some way to tell you there is no more input.  That way is to return `-1` -- in your code, if that happens then your loop runs away, `gethchar()` just keeps returning `-1` over and over and over and you keep allocating memory until it is all gone.

EDIT: One possible fix:

```
int c;

do {
    /* ... */
    c = getchar();
    if (c < 0) c = '\0';        /* one idea, handle this case as you see fit */
    if (c == '\n') c = '\0';
} while ((str[length++] = c) != '\0');
```

Comment: you still have several issues below this which others have addressed at least partially

Comment: OK i get it, but how can i achieve what i want (to have a string of any length), what function should i use?

Comment: What I supplied you with above plus your `if(length >= memo) ...` code (which looks correct to me) put where I wrote `/* ... */` will do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! It is perfectly working. One more fix was needed that i missed and that is the `i < wordcount-1` as BLUEPIXY said above.

Comment: `getchar` returns `EOF` on failure. This could be any negative integer but your code is only testing `-1`.